# setParameter for an array property with JACOB

Tags: java, vb.net, jacob

I have the following VB code :

```
Set QuoteRequest = Quotes.Add
With QuoteRequest
    .No = 1
    .QuoteCode(0)="101"
    .Code(0)="NAME1"
    .Code(1)="NAME2"
End With
```

I use JACOB to access that COM object.

```
quoteRequest.setProperty("No",1);
quoteRequest.setProperty("QuoteCode(0)","101");
quoteRequest.setProperty("Code(0)", "NAME1");
quoteRequest.setProperty("Code(1)", "NAME2");
```

But this leads to exception

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map to dispid: QuoteCode(0)
```

How can I pass that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import com.jacob.com.*;
import com.jacob.activeX.*;

static void setProperty(Dispatch d, String sName, String sIndex, String sValue) {
  Variant av[] = { new Variant(sIndex), new Variant(sValue) };
  Dispatch.invokev(d, sName, Dispatch.Put, av, NO_INT_ARGS).safeRelease();
  av[0].safeRelease(); av[1].safeRelease();
  }
```

That's the code I used. Works for me, however I was doing some changes to Jacob, to force garbaging of unused variants. Hard to say what I exactly did, it was years ago :)

Comment: NO_INT_ARGS - what is this parameter?

Comment: I'm having a `com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Type mismatch` exception when running this...

Comment: `NO_INT_ARGS`: UTSL. Type mismatch: my code is for cases, where property is indexed by string. You have to modify it a bit. You need `int iIndex` in place of `String sIndex`.