# jacob com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: CardNumber[0] git hub ZkemSDK project

Tags: java, jacob, time-and-attendance

i am in project to connect with access control and attendance machine
i found this project that connect to same type using java in github
but in line that i want to Set CardNumber property i have an exception 
"com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't map name to dispid: CardNumber[0]"
can some body give me a hand

https://github.com/lookskystar/ZKKQProject/blob/master/ZKKQProject/src/com/zkkq/uitl/ZkemSDK.java

```
public class ZkemSDK 
{
    private static ActiveXComponent zkem ;

    public   ZkemSDK(){

        zkem = new ActiveXComponent("zkemkeeper.ZKEM.1");
        System.out.println("done ");
    }
    public boolean connect(String address,int port, int machineNum) throws Exception{

        boolean result = zkem.invoke("Connect_NET",address,port).getBoolean();
    }

    public boolean SetUserInfo(int machineNum,int enrollNo2,String userName,String password,int privelage ,boolean flag) {

        Variant dwUserName = new Variant(userName,true);
        Variant dwPassword = new Variant(password,true);
        Variant dwPrivelage = new Variant(privelage,true);
        Variant dwEnrollNo = new Variant(enrollNo2,true);
        Variant dwMachineNum= new Variant(machineNum,true);

        /****/

        zkem.setProperty("CardNumber[0]",454545);
        /****/

        Variant vResult = Dispatch.call(zkem,"SetUserInfo",dwMachineNum, dwEnrollNo, dwUserName, dwPassword, dwPrivelage,true);


        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found somebody override setProperty to be able to add array
in this link
[setParameter for an array property with JACOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871675/setparameter-for-an-array-property-with-jacob)
 my code was this

```
public static void setProperty(Dispatch d, String sName, String sIndex, String sValue) {
      Variant av[] = { new Variant(sIndex), new Variant(sValue) };
      int j[]= {0};
      Dispatch.invokev(d, sName, Dispatch.Put, av,j).safeRelease();
      av[0].safeRelease(); av[1].safeRelease();
      }
```

and calling was like this

```
this.setProperty(zkem,"CardNumber","0","2599970");
```

before this line

```
Variant vResult = Dispatch.call(zkem,"SetUserInfo",dwMachineNum, dwEnrollNo, dwUserName, dwPassword, dwPrivelage,true);
```